# how to remove a row and column simultaneously of Nested List in python 3

Tags: python

I'd like a little help... I need to remove a column and row at the same time from the nested list using the number of the row and column (python 3.8). Is there a simple way to do this?

`L = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`   (row=0 and col=1)  ;

```
newL = [[5,6],[7,8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `numpy` for stuff like this.

```
import numpy as np

row = 0
col = 1

L = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
newL = np.delete(L, row, axis=0)
newL = np.delete(newL, col, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` in a list comprehension:

```
L = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
row = 0
col = 1

temp = [x for i, x in enumerate(L) if i != row]

res = list(map(list, zip(*[y for x, y in enumerate(zip(*temp), 1) if x != col])))
# [[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward answer is:

```
import copy
L = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def remove(l, row, column):
    new_list = copy.deepcopy(l)

    if row in range(len(new_list)): # check to avoid IndexOutOfBound
        del new_list[row]
    for row in new_list:
        if column in range(len(row)):  # check to avoid IndexOutOfBound
            del row[column]
    return new_list

remove(L, 1, 1)
```

That returns:

```
[[1, 3], [7, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested list comprehension without modifying original list

```
def remove_row_col(L, row, col):
    if row not in range(len(L)):
        return
    if col not in range(len(L[0])):
        return
    return [[c for c in r[:col] + r[col + 1 :]] for r in L[:row] + L[row + 1 :]]
```

usage samples

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
    print(remove_row_col(L, 0, 1))
    print(remove_row_col(L, 1, 1))
    print(remove_row_col(L, 1, 2))
    print(remove_row_col(L, 1, 3))
```

outputs

```
[[4, 6], [7, 9]]
[[1, 3], [7, 9]]
[[1, 2], [7, 8]]
None
```

Or you can just delete row and iterate col (will modify the array)

```
del L[row]
for r in L:
  del r[col]
```